# Why hasn't the USA's Supreme Court made any official decisions to the cases they have heard in over a year?

Tags: united-states, supreme-court

It looks like there has been exactly two case from the supreme court [2022-2023 term](https://www.oyez.org/cases/2022) that had a decision rendered, there are even some cases from the past term that don't yet have decisions yet.  I understand taking time to make a final decision, but how does the supreme court fail to make (almost) any decisions in over a year's time?  Of the two they did decide on one took less then a month to come to a verdict on, why are the rest taking more then a year?

Has the supreme court always been this slow in rendering decisions in the past?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "over a year's time"? That sounds like it means "since February 2022," but [the Court has decided numerous cases since then](https://www.oyez.org/cases/2021). (Remember: The 2022-23 term only began in October, so everything decided before October 2022 will be listed under the 2021-22 term.)

Comment: Do you mean SCOTUS or any of the various state supreme courts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Supreme Court terms start the first Monday in October, and usually end sometime in June or July, so most of the '2022' term is actually in 2023. The 2022 term has only decided two cases so far (both in 2023), but the 2021 term decided many cases in 2022.

From the Supreme Court's [The Court and Its Procedures](https://www.supremecourt.gov/about/procedures.aspx) page:

> A Term of the Supreme Court begins, by statute, on the first Monday in October. Usually Court sessions continue until late June or early July. The Term is divided between "sittings," when the Justices hear cases and deliver opinions, and intervening "recesses," when they consider the business before the Court and write opinions. Sittings and recesses alternate at approximately two-week intervals.
>
> ...
>
> Opinions are typically released on Tuesday and Wednesday mornings and on the third Monday of each sitting, when the Court takes the Bench but no arguments are heard.
>
> The Court maintains this schedule each Term until all cases ready for submission have been heard and decided. In May and June the Court sits only to announce orders and opinions.

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_United_States_Supreme_Court_cases) has links to lists of all cases the Supreme Court has decided since 1999. The page for the [2022 term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_term_opinions_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States) lists the same two cases as your source, however if you go to the page for the [2021 term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_term_opinions_of_the_Supreme_Court_of_the_United_States) you'll see that about 60 cases were decided in 2022. I didn't go through all the lists, but from a quick look it seems like they decide around 60-80 cases per year.